# Input datalist inside shadow dom not working

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, html-input, html-datalist

I am trying to create with customElements my own `input` button with `list` attribute and `datalist` element. But it is not working when created inside a shadow dom.

HTML:

```
<test-input></test-input>
```

Javascript:

```
class InputClass extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
        input.type = 'text';
        input.setAttribute('list', 'myList');
        shadow.appendChild(input);

        var datalist = document.createElement('DATALIST');
        datalist.id = 'myList';
        shadow.appendChild(datalist);

        var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
        option.value ="testValue";
        option.innerHTML = "testInnerHTML";
        datalist.appendChild(option);
    }
}
customElements.define('test-input', InputClass);
```

This code does not work. But when I append the elements `input` and `datalist` outside the shadow dom (document.body) the feature works.

/edit: Tested with:

- Firefox 65.0.2: not working
- Google Chrome 72.0.3626.121: working

So it seems to be a Firefox Bug?

Comment: Did you test older version of Firefox i.e. Firefox 40?

Comment: No. This issue is part of an application in our companys local network. Everybody uses the latest Firefox version there. So I have to get it right with version 65.0.2.

Comment: Yes it's a Firefox bug.

Comment: Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: I found that bug on Mozillas bug tracker (1489440). It is already marked as fixed in Firefox 66 and release date should be 19th March. So no workaround needed.